# How do I fix Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my laptop and it was working fine, but today whenever I try to turn it on I can't some weird text appears and I don't know what it is or what to do. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but it didn't work. Whenever I try to turn on the laptop right before the aforementioned screen, I see a screen with three boot options.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWfKJ.jpg

Comment: I've never seen that before. Can you boot to a live CD?

Comment: Loks like a graphics glitch. Intel card?

Comment: @vanadium yes it's a Intel card

Comment: @cocomac No the only way i can boot is from a USB

Comment: Lets see boot configuration. What brand/model system? What version of Ubuntu? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Try whether adding ` i915.enable_psr=0` to the kernel boot parameters (`/etc/default/grub`) solves the issue. If not, just remove that parameter again.